# Highlight "antd" menu-item when route is changed from redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

I am using the "antd" framework for a react app and have one slight issues with menus, more precisely with highlighting the currently selected menu item.

I found the following solution that works fine when a link is called, an url is entered directly to a specific page and when "back" is pressed:

```
render() {
    const href = window.location.href.split('/');
    const href2 = href[3];
 <Menu
        mode="horizontal"
        theme="dark"
        defaultSelectedKeys={['/' + href2]}
        selectedKeys={['/' + href2]}
      >
    <Menu.Item key="/">
      ...
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="/test">
       ...
    </Menu.Item>
 <Menu>
```

My problem happens when I set my route from a redux saga (with history.push), I can then see that the "navigation bar" component gets rendered/updated before the "history.push" action is called in the saga.

How can I get my "navigation bar" component to be re-rendered after every route change (however the route change is done). My "navigation bar" is currently a component, because I tried to use the different events, but none of them gets fired. It could also be a functional component (it has no state) it that helps.

I also tried suggestions from "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054657/react-routerantd-how-to-highlight-a-menu-item-when-press-back-forward-button" but could not get it to work with my use case

Comment: Are you using react-router in your project?

Comment: yes, I am using "<Router history={history}>" in order to be able to push the history from my saga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `react-router` library you shouldn't use `window.location` object. In your example of code, you're using the class component. In this case the component in `<Route>` receives `location` prop. And you can use it when you want

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // will be true
    const locationChanged =
      this.props.location !== prevProps.location;
  }
}

<Route component={Comp} />;
```

Comment: Thank you for that example.

In my main app I have a "<navbar />" component and then some "<Switch> <Route>..." for the individual routes. But the "navbar" component is not defined as a route (as it only contains the menu item/links).
My goal is to have the "navbar" component re-rendered whenever a route is called (and however it is called)
I don't think that I can apply the code above to my navbar component or do I missunderstand something ?

Comment: I think I found a solution based on your answer above.
I pass the "location.pathname" from my main "app.tsx" to the "navbar" component:
<Navbar path={location.pathname as string} />
That way my component gets re-rendered on every change